# What have we lost?(a cipher of indeterminate value)

Tags: cipher

A strange man in a bow tie with a serious comb-over left you this:

[image: Mysterious piece of paper...]

[image: Second half of mysterious piece of paper...]

"A simple cipher," he says, "and I leave it to you to find out what has been lost."
Can you?

> On an OOC note, I have no idea how hard this would be…?  Also, sorry for the bad image quality.

Comment: This looks like an abugida of some sort...

Comment: Is the text on the back of the paper of any importance? Is it the decrypted text?

Comment: The text on the back is completely insignificant, sorry about that...

Comment: What looks to be punctuation (e.g., some commas, the question mark at the end) - can we assume that that is in fact punctuation?

Comment: Yes, it is in fact, actually punctuation

Comment: The plaintext is a quote from a source I have made riddles on before.  I'm not sure if this is solvable at all, since I made up the cipher myself...

Comment: It's difficult to tell due to the fact that it's handwritten, but I see two variations on the そ character -- one of which is slightly more curved throughout, and one of which is perfectly straight.  Are these the same character or intentionally different?

Comment: @feelinferrety They are intentional different, good catch. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Plaintext:

> We knew that land once, You and I,
> and once we wandered there
> in the long days now long gone by,
> a dark child and a fair.
> Was it on the paths of firelight thought
> in winter cold and white,
> or in the blue-spun twilit hours
> of little early tucked-up beds
> in drowsy summer night,
> that you and I in Sleep went down
> to meet each other there,
> your dark hair on your white nightgown
> and mine was tangled fair?
>  - J. R. R. Tolkien, *The Little House of Lost Play: Mar Vanwa Tyalieva*

Solve path:

> The word separators were the biggest clue. I began by highlighting all of the repeated words. The separators also told me the very first word could not be a one-letter word, or else there are too many unique one-letter words (and I'm already expecting one extra for `the`). This tells me the horizontal line is a separate letter. There aren't many two-letter words I expect to find at the beginning of a sentence, mostly `IF`, `NO`, or `WE`. The most frequent three-letter word is either `THE` or `AND`. After assuming `WE` and `AND`, the second repetition of `WE` was right next to a long word beginning with `W` and containing a few of `NDE`. A pattern search turned up the word `WANDERED`, which confirmed that the horizontal stroke across the letter meant a letter `E` followed that letter, and likewise the curve below means `A`. Then, a word following `WE` and ending in `W` has to be `KNEW`. I continued solving it as a simple substitution and learned that the vowels have whole-symbol forms (in addition to the combining forms) for when they appear at the beginning of a word, and in other places.

> By the time I completed the line `in the long days now long gone by`, I decided to google it and found the source. So I only discovered the "double letter" combining symbol after the fact.

The only tools I used were the drawing program Inkscape, and a small program I wrote for finding dictionary words according to various patterns.

Answer (score 7):

#### Transcript

`Z- AT-Z (R_N) D_TOETJ-, B|C STO LY,
STO ETF Z- Z_TO-Z-O (R-Z)F
LT G D|TV O_BQ T|Z D|TV V|T- KB
S O_ZA JR*DO STO S W_LZ
Z_Q L() ET GU_(RQ) EW W*Z-D*VR()
LT Z*T(FZ) J|DO STO ZR*(F),
@Z LT (R-) T D.F QU.T (Z*D*)() R|CZQ
EW F_ZDB (CJ)A-O CUK-OQ`

`LT OZ|ZQB Q.H~FZ T*VR()
(B_D) B|C STO LY LT QDF~U Z-T() O|ZT
(E) UF~() F_JR E(R-Z) (R-Z-),
B|CZ O_ZA R_LZ ET B|CZ ZR*(F) T*VR(V|Z)T
STO H*T- Z_Q (ST)VD-O W_LZ?`

Key:

- `A`: weird curly A
- `B`: beak pointing northeast
- `C`: curly spiral
- `D`: delta
- `E`: @
- `F`: flower
- `G`: γ
- `H`: horseshoe
- `J`: curly J (maybe a cursive T?)
- `K`: ampersand
- `L`: weird lambda
- `N`: dome character
- `O`: circle
- `Q`: double circle
- `R`: manta ray-ish shape (ginkgo leaf, maybe?)
- `S`: integral sign
- `T`: treble clef
- `U`: backward ampersand
- `V`: spark on top of Aries symbol
- `W`: waves
- `Z`: zigzaggy 3
- `-`: bar through previous symbol
- `_`: cup under previous symbol
- `~`: tilde over previous symbol
- `*`: asterisk over previous symbol
- `|`: vertical bar through previous symbol
- `.`: dot under previous symbol
- `()`: dome over enclosed symbols

Comment: line 7 character 1 should be E

Answer (score 5):

Out of curiosity, I tried to extract the text from the back of the papers, in case there's a clue.  The pictures are pretty noisy (probably a cell phone camera) so it's difficult, here's the best I could do:

[image]
[image]

It appears to be a letter of some sort.  I can read the date (January or February 28, 2016) on the top of the first page; I can see a fragment "-ing our" at the end of the third or fourth line on the same page; and I can see a signature in the middle of the second page.